How to Connect Azure Function to Externally Hosted SQL Server Database?
I'm developing an Azure Function in .NET that needs to connect to a SQL Server database hosted externally on a shared hosting provider (not Azure SQL Database). I've followed several tutorials, but I'm encountering issues with establishing a connection to the database.
Here's what I've done so far:
Created an Azure Function App in the Azure Portal using the .NET runtime stack.
Added a new HTTP-triggered function named HttpTriggerWithSql.
Configured the SQL Server connection string in the Function App's settings:
Name: SqlConnectionString
Value:  Server=myserver.sharedhosting.com;Database=mydatabase;User Id=myusername;Password=mypassword;
string connectionString = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("SqlConnectionString", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Process);


Implemented the database connection logic:


using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
{
    await conn.OpenAsync();
    string query = "SELECT TOP 1 * FROM MyTable";

    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn))
    {
        SqlDataReader reader = await cmd.ExecuteReaderAsync();
        // Process data...
    }
}

The Issue:
When I run the function, I get the following error:

2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Information]   Executing 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=ba7ed57f-67b8-40d3-88d4-ba2567c74bea)
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   Function compilation error
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(7,42): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Http' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(15,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpTriggerAttribute' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(15,10): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'HttpTrigger' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(15,22): error CS0103: The name 'AuthorizationLevel' does not exist in the current context
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(15,66): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Route' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(25,20): error CS1069: The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(25,45): error CS1069: The type name 'SqlConnection' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(31,24): error CS1069: The type name 'SqlCommand' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(31,45): error CS1069: The type name 'SqlCommand' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   run.csx(33,21): error CS1069: The type name 'SqlDataReader' could not be found in the namespace 'System.Data.SqlClient'. This type has been forwarded to assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' Consider adding a reference to that assembly.
2024-10-16T20:59:07Z   [Error]   Executed 'Functions.HttpTrigger1' (Failed, Id=ba7ed57f-67b8-40d3-88d4-ba2567c74bea, Duration=4ms)


You need to reference the missing assemblies in the function app.  The same as if you were writing the app in visual studio.  Notice you also have an implicit reference to System.Data.SqlClient - the compiler guessed that this the definition of SqlDataReader you wanted to use, you'll want to fix any of those that pop up as well.

@maztt, Check if below solution helps.

To resolve the errors, you have to install below NuGet packages in your function project as @Kevin mentioned in the comments.
.csproj:
  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Functions" Version="4.5.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.Data.SqlClient" Version="4.8.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Sql" Version="3.0.534" />
  </ItemGroup>

Include the below namespaces in function.cs:
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs;
using Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Extensions.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

I am able to run your code without any errors:

Use below code to connect Azure Function to SQL Server Database and fetch the data:
Code Snippet:
[FunctionName("GetToDoItem")]
public static IActionResult Run(
  [HttpTrigger(AuthorizationLevel.Anonymous, "get", Route = "gettodoitem")] HttpRequest req,
  [Sql(commandText: "select [Name], [CreatedAt] from dbo.table1 where Id = @Id",
     commandType: System.Data.CommandType.Text,
     parameters: "@Id={Query.Id}",
     connectionStringSetting: "SqlConnectionString")]
 IEnumerable<ToDoItem> toDoItem)
 {
     var todoItem = toDoItem.FirstOrDefault();

     if (todoItem == null)
     {
         return new NotFoundResult();
     }

     return new OkObjectResult(todoItem);
 }

Response:
Functions:

        GetToDoItem: [GET] http://localhost:7157/api/gettodoitem

For detailed output, run func with --verbose flag.
[2024-10-21T10:22:50.800Z] Host lock lease acquired by instance ID '000000000000000000000000F72731CC'.
[2024-10-21T10:22:53.403Z] Executing 'Functions.GetToDoItem' (Reason='This function was programmatically called via the host APIs.', Id=4a6d4d60-bfdc-40e1-aff7-e760891184b6)
[2024-10-21T10:23:05.198Z] Executing OkObjectResult, writing value of type 'FunctionApp6.ToDoItem'.
[2024-10-21T10:23:05.275Z] Executed 'Functions.GetToDoItem' (Succeeded, Id=4a6d4d60-bfdc-40e1-aff7-e760891184b6, Duration=11894ms)


